# Logwatch for multiple log 'root directories' on a central log server?

Tags: logwatch, centralized-logging

I have multiple clusters, each with a service machine that also collects all the logs (rsyslog and RELP). I started separating them to `/data/logs/<hostname>/*` so the `messages`, `maillog` and other files are separate for each remote host in its own directory, rather than mix them all in under unified logs in `/var/log`.

However I still want Logwatch to give me one report on the entire cluster, but I can't specify multiple `LogDir` settings. naturally I also prefer not to customize all the specific paths in dozens of locations under `logfiles` if I can find a shortcut, but I can't think of one. Help?